# how to modify a directive processor C

Tags: c, linux

When I compile my source code to print *Hello from 2014* using the current year, without having to edit the source code. I thought about making a new header. My source is `year.c` so the header would be `year.h`.

Is there a way to make a function that returns YEAR + 1?

Is there another way of doing it? If so, how? I don't know how to make a header file either.

My code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef YEAR
  #define YEAR "2013"
#endif

int main() {
    printf("Hello from" YEAR ); return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess you're looking for: define `YEAR` as integer rather than string and then you can use the `+` operator: `#define YEAR 2013`. And on `printf()` you should do `printf("Hello from %d", YEAR + 1);` because it is no longer a string literal that you can concat

Comment: If you want to embed the date/year when the source was compiled, take a look at the standard `__DATE__` macro (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html).

Comment: i ment that i want to print 2014 , not YEAR + 1, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, also, [predefine a macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) at compile time passing parameters to the compiler, like this:

```
-D name=definition
```

If you're using GCC, you can compile your code like this:

```
gcc -D YEAR=2014 myProgram.c -o myProgram
```

This way, you have full control of your macro at compile time, without the need to change your code. This option is very useful to handle debugging information.

Note that this macro is defined before the source file is preprocessed, so by the time your code hits `#ifndef YEAR`, there will already be a macro named `YEAR`.

---

Also, you should also update your `printf()` call to this:

```
printf("Hello from %d", YEAR);
```

since `YEAR` is considered to be a numberic value, and not a string literal.

Comment: year.c:8:30: note: in expansion of macro'YEAR'     printf(Bla bla);

Comment: and if i don't have to change to int ? i need a string , i can't do something like gcc -D YEAR="2014" ...?

Comment: Yes, by doing:  `-D YEAR='"2014"' `. Note the extra `'`, so that your shell interpreter doesn't get confused and tries to interpret it itself.

Comment: i wrote how you told me and the output is still Hello from 2013. It does not change to 2014 either way i am tryng

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know how to make a header file either.

To use a header file, you simply refer to it using `#include`.

In your example, in your file `year.c` simply add:

```
#include "year.h"
```

Then obviously create the text file `text.h` with the appropriate content.

One recommended practice, though not essential, is to use a header file "wrapper" that prevents the header file from being read repeatedly (wasting time re-processing the same file), This is most beneficial in large projects where the complex inter-dependency make it easy to indirectly include the same header file multiple times.

Example:

```
/* year.h - Documentation */

#ifndef YEAR_H
#defined YEAR_H
...
/* header file's 'actual' content */
#define CURRENT_YEAR "2014"
...
#endif
/* ifndef YEAR_H */
```

---

> When I compile my source code to print Hello from 2014 using the current year, without having to edit the source code.

There are multiple methods to achieve this, I will show one such way.

In Standard C (C89/90, C99, or C11) the compiler (or its preprocessor) will automatically generate a macro definition for `__DATE__` as a string containing the date including the year.

You can write a function that parses this string to return only the year, as an integer value.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_year_compiled(void) {
   char* date = __DATE__;
   char *year;

   year = date + strlen(date) - 4; /* Pointer arithmetic for fun and profit */
   return atoi(year);
}
```

---

> Is there a way to make a function that returns YEAR + 1?

This can be easily done as an extension to the previous question.

Kudos to @Andrew-Medico for mentioning `__DATE__` first.

Answer (score 1):

Yoy can redefine a macro, in this way:

```
 #ifdef YEAR
   #undef YEAR   // This line destroys the "old" definition of YEAR
 #endif

 #define YEAR "2014"
```